# Converting an ip address to binary representation

Tags: python, ip-address

I want to get the bytes representation of an ip address (big endian, 4 bytes).

I'm using Python 2 and I am using this module: https://github.com/phihag/ipaddress

If I want to get the bytes representation of `127.0.0.1`, I get the expected result.

```
>>> ip_address(u'127.0.0.1').packed
'\x7f\x00\x00\x01'
```

But for `52.4.20.183`, I am getting this result:

```
>>> ip_address(u'52.4.20.183').packed
'4\x04\x14\xb7'
```

This format looks odd to me, especially the leading `4`. I was expecting it to be `\x34\x04\x14\xB7`. But apparently, both are the same:

```
>>> ipaddress.IPv4Address(b'4\x04\x14\xb7')
IPv4Address(u'52.4.20.183')
>>> ipaddress.IPv4Address(b'\x34\x04\x14\xB7')
IPv4Address(u'52.4.20.183')
```

Why is the format for `52.4.20.183` `4\x04\x14\xb7` and where can I find more information about it?

Comment: Turns out that `'4'` is the ASCII representation for the byte value 52, see http://www.asciitable.com/. In other words: `b'4' == b'\x34' == bytes([52])`.

Comment: Per its description, `packed` returns a `bytes` object, which is more or less derived from a regular `string`. See [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects) for a longer explanation. You can find more information in that official documentation as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characters `'4'` and `'\x34'` are equivalent. Both represent the value 52.

Comment: Thanks! Can you also explain, why 4 and \x34 are the same?

Comment: @mitchkman every character has a value. The value of the character `4` is 52 in pretty much all modern encodings (ASCII / ANSI / UTF-8 / ISO-8859-* 
 / etc...).

Comment: Thanks, looking at an ASCII table solved the mystery

Comment: The leading \x escape sequence means  that the character is interpreted as a hex digit and in hex representation 34 translates to 52(decimal).